# Save 400 error in Safari only

Tags: backbone.js, http-status-code-400

I am calling `save()` on a Backbone model. This works in every version of every browser I have tried **except** Safari and Safari on iOS.

In those 2 browsers the call fails before hitting the server with a `400 Bad Request` error.
The call looks like `../common/User/`

My `User` model looks like this:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({

    idAttribute: "UserId",
    initialize: function() {
    }, 

    url: function () {
        var base = 'common/User/';
        return (this.isNew()) ? base : base + this.id;
    },...
```

The information I am trying to save looks like this:

```
{"BrowserType":"Safari","BrowserVersion":5.1,"ApplicationPath":"index"}
```

I not sure what other information I could provide to be helpful.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

**EDIT**
The Request Header looks like:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/json
Origin:http://localhost:1087
Referer:http://localhost:1087/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: If you open Webinspector, what is the request URL in the header?

Comment: http://localhost:1087/common/User/  locally... With a slash at the end... (i cant figure out how to escape it here)

Comment: Can't reproduce error. Can you post the complete request header? What server do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Update the `User` model's `url` method to include a trailing slash:

```
url: function () {
    var base = 'common/User/';
    return (this.isNew()) ? base : base + this.id + "/";
},
```

I was having the same issues in my Backbone project -- all `POST`/`PUT`/`PATCH` requests for a particular model were failing in Safari and Mobile Safari although I had no problems in other browsers. As [@mu is too short's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144026/save-400-error-in-safari-only#comment14609893_11144026) suggests, adding a trailing slash to my model's `url` method fixed the issue.